# Service Unit test SpringFramework

Tags: java, unit-testing

These are service and repository classes which i am trying to test.

```
 @Service
public class BookServiceImpl implements BookService {

    @Autowired
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Override
    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        return bookRepository.getAllBooks();
    }

    @Override
    public Book getBookById(int productID) {
        return bookRepository.getBookById(productID);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getBookByCategory(String category) {
        return bookRepository.getBookByCategory(category);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Book> getBooksByFilter(Map<String, List<String>> filterParams) {
        return bookRepository.getBooksByFilter(filterParams);
    }

}

@Repository
@Configuration
public class InMemoryBookRepository implements BookRepository {

    private List<Book> listOfProducts = new ArrayList<Book>();

    public InMemoryBookRepository() {
        Book algorithms = new Book(1, "Book", "Book", 29);
        algorithms.setDescription("description.");
        algorithms.setCondition("Available");
        algorithms.setUnitsInStock(4);
        algorithms.setCategory("java");
        algorithms.setManufacturer("Nenov");
        listOfProducts.add(algorithms);
        Book book2 = new Book(2, "Thinking in Java", "Bruce Ekel", 5352);
        book2.setDescription("Description");
        book2.setCondition("Available");
        book2.setUnitsInStock(100);
        book2.setCategory("programming");
        book2.setManufacturer("Nikola");
        listOfProducts.add(book2);
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getAllBooks() {
        return listOfProducts;
    }

    @Override
    public Book getBookById(int bookId) {
        Book bookById = null;
        for (Book book : listOfProducts) {
            if (book != null && book.getId() != 0) {
                bookById = book;
                break;
            }
        }
        return bookById;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Book> getBookByCategory(String category) {
        List<Book> productsByCategory = new ArrayList<Book>();
        for (Book book : listOfProducts) {
            if (category.equalsIgnoreCase(book.getCategory())) {
                productsByCategory.add(book);
            }
        }
        return productsByCategory;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Book> getBooksByFilter(Map<String, List<String>> filterParams) {
        Set<Book> productsByBrand = new HashSet<Book>();
        Set<Book> productsByCategory = new HashSet<Book>();
        Set<String> criterias = filterParams.keySet();
        if (criterias.contains("brand")) {
            for (String brandName : filterParams.get("brand")) {
                for (Book book : listOfProducts) {
                    if (brandName.equalsIgnoreCase(book.getManufacturer())) {
                        productsByBrand.add(book);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (criterias.contains("category")) {
            for (String category : filterParams.get("category")) {
                productsByCategory.addAll(this.getBookByCategory(category));
            }
        }
        productsByCategory.retainAll(productsByBrand);
        return productsByCategory;
    }

}
```

I am trying to make unit test on service but a have null pointer exception. I hope someone will help. If you need more code please notify me.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration({ "Context.xml" })
public class BookServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private BookRepository bookRepository;

    @Test
    public void testGetBookById() {
        Book book = new Book(1, "Book", "Book", 29);

        int id = book.getId();

        assertNotNull("Object can not have null id ", id);

        Book searchedBook = bookRepository.getBookById(id); // nullpointer here !
        assertNotNull("Book should be found ", searchedBook);
        assertTrue("Found book id should be equal to id being searched", searchedBook.getId() == 1);
    }
}
```

Context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="bookRepository" name="bookRepository" class="org.mockito.Mockito"
        factory-method="mock">
        <constructor-arg value="com.book.contracts.BookRepository" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at store.BookServiceTest.testGetBookById(BookServiceTest.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

StackTrace with `@Autowired`

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Book should be found 
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertTrue(Assert.java:41)
    at org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull(Assert.java:712)
    at store.BookServiceTest.testGetBookById(BookServiceTest.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

EDIT:

```
@Test
    public void testGetBookById() {
        Book book = new Book(1, "Book", "Book", 29);

        int id = book.getId();
        assertNotNull("Object can not have null id ", id);

        Book searchedBook = bookRepository.getBookById(id);
        Assertions.assertThat( searchedBook ).isNotNull();
        assertTrue("Found book id should be equal to id being searched", searchedBook.getId() == 1);
    }
```

Stacktrace

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expecting actual value not to be null
    at org.fest.assertions.Fail.failure(Fail.java:228)
    at org.fest.assertions.Fail.fail(Fail.java:167)
    at org.fest.assertions.Fail.failIfActualIsNull(Fail.java:100)
    at org.fest.assertions.GenericAssert.isNotNull(GenericAssert.java:238)
    at store.BookServiceTest.testGetBookById(BookServiceTest.java:31)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:73)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:224)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:83)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:68)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:163)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace?

Comment: @IlGala Stack Trace added.

Comment: Did you try '@InjectMocks' and '@Autowired' on this repository variable ?

Comment: @Sercan Ozdemir with InjectMocj the problem is the same and with Autowired i will copy the stactrace in my question.

Comment: That means @Autowired is working....

Comment: Use constructor injection instead of field injection. You can usually eliminate the need for a test context entirely.

Comment: @chrylis Please give an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you initialize your own context with Spring you don't have to type put `@Mock` annotation. Just put `@Autowired` and you are fine to go.

```
@Autowired
private BookRepository bookRepository;
```

After you put `@Autowired` I suggest you to use fest.assertions class such as:

```
Assertions.assertThat( myBook ).isNotNull();
```

And the import is:

```
import org.fest.assertions.Assertions;
```

**Edit:** Since you are using `java.lang` assertions, you will always get exceptions.

> The meaning of an AssertionError is that something happened that the
>   developer thought was impossible to happen.
>
> So if an AssertionError is ever thrown, it is a clear sign of a
>   programming error.

So you have to look forward for http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.easytesting/fest-assert if you are using maven, otherwise download it as jar and add it to your dependencies. Then you can use my suggestion.

Comment: Where i have to put this - Assertions.assertThat( myBook ).isNotNull();

Comment: That was only a suggestion instead of using         assertNotNull("Book should be found ", searchedBook); You shouldn't get an exception for an assert situation.

Comment: I can not import it but... it does not matter.Do you know how to fix the problem with Autowired field?

Comment: Can you please try to check if bookRepository variable is null ?

Comment: Also try to add  <context:component-scan base-package="com.book" /> to your context.xml and remove other bean definitions with mockito from your context.xml

Comment: it is not null. Just check it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97989/discussion-between-sercan-ozdemir-and-nosuchuserexception).

Comment: Problem is fixed. I edit Context.xml as you suggest.

Comment: I'm glad you've made it. Just don't forget you have to use another context with your junit tests to not struggle with real application's context.xml. Because with this method you are using a real context.xml and connecting to the directly your database, instead of that you can create a new context.xml and scan it in your tests therefore you can connect another database with this new context.xml